# Adding many items to ListView is laggy and takes a while

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to create a Hex Editor, and in order to do that I have created a layout which allows me to "open" a file and use it. When I open the file I want to have the offsets on the left.

The problem is, whenever I load the file, I loop over the amount of rows and add each offset number to the "richtext" box.

My design:

[image: https://gyazo.com/43c847aff9a0c19bee0e0ae6cc5a4cc8]

My code:

```
private void changeTable()
{
    // File content is the selected file's content
    int rowCount = (fileContent.Length + bytesPerLine) / bytesPerLine;
    this.richTextBox1.ResetText();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText("0x" + i.ToString("X").PadLeft(8, '0') + "\n");
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the richtext object into a ListView but that is even slower. Are there more efficient or better solutions?

Comment: [`BeginUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8), [`EndUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

A **RichTextBox** is not going to be high-performance control because it is a visual GUI component, etc. But, you're treating it like it is some sort of high-performance data buffer that you're trying to update continuously. The simplest thing to do here is to "double-buffer" the control by building the string value separately in memory. Then one single time at the end, update the RichTextBox.

```
private void changeTable()
{
    // File content is the selected file's content
    int rowCount = (fileContent.Length + bytesPerLine) / bytesPerLine;
    this.richTextBox1.ResetText();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        sb.Append("0x" + i.ToString("X").PadLeft(8, '0') + "\n");
    }
    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
}
```